# C# - How to move a node and its sub-nodes to another place within a XML document?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML file structure like this:

```
<root>
    <list>
        <item1>item 1</item1>
        <item2>item 2</item2>
        <item3>item 3</item3>
        <item4>item 4</item4>
    </list>
    <generated-items>
        <item5>item 5</item5>
        <item6>item 6</item6>
    </generated-items>
</root>
```

What I want to do is move the generated-list node and its sub-nodes to make it a sub-node within the list node.

So the final result should be like this:

```
<root>
    <list>
        <item1>item 1</item1>
        <item2>item 2</item2>
        <item3>item 3</item3>
        <item4>item 4</item4>
        <generated-items>
            <item5>item 5</item5>
            <item6>item 6</item6>
        </generated-items>
    </list>
</root>
```

Hope someone can help me find the best solution for this.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement root = doc.Root;

            XElement list = root.Element("list");
            XElement items = root.Element("generated-items");

            list.Add(new XElement(items));
            items.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there like this in python?

Comment: What about powershell?  Any c# code can be converted to powershell.